# What was the [Shift+S > Origin to Cursor] plugin I had before?

Tags: 3d-cursor, origin

Does anyone know what plugin had that feature? I had an issue with my drive, had to format it. I had some plugin  that added option to "set origin to cursor" under Shift+S menu. Anyone knows what plugin does that?

Comment: What Blender version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using v 2.82

Comment: You can access it with Right Click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm asking. It's really intuitive to have it under Shift+S and some plugin had that feature, I'm looking for that plugin.

Comment: Yes I see what you are talking about. There were 2 pie-menus add-ons in previous versions but now there is only one, so I guess this is that. You may be able to find it on github or export it from a previous version. Alternatively you can add the shortcut to your quick-favorites

Comment: Well, I had it on 2.82. I lost all the plugins cause of my SATA cable getting loose (always make sure another cable doesn't push it half way out before powering your PC! ;) ). It destroyed my files system on system drive (another tip - keep restore points on a different drive...), where blender was installed, so I had to format.